# Date format for the following dates?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show a date time in the following format 01-Mar-2000 10:10:10 PM/AM.

How to achieve it?

Please suggest a one line answer to write optimized code.

Comment: Can you include what you;ve tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [intl package DateFormat](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html).

The format will be `DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss a");`

single line will be

```dart
DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss a").format(dateTime);
```

```dart
final dateTime = DateTime.now();
DateFormat formater = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss a");
final data = formater.format(dateTime);
print(data);//30-10-2022 4:14:19 PM
```